# Magento API - Category Create - Default Product Listing Sort by does not exist

Tags: magento-1.9, php, api, soap

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1] Default Product Listing
>   Sort by does not exist in Available Product Listing Sort By.

I cannot figure out why Magento keeps giving me this error? Using the default sort by position.

```
    $result = $client->catalogCategoryCreate($session, 2, array(
    'name' => $cat_name,
    'is_active' => 1,
    'available_sort_by' => array('position'),
    'custom_design' => null,
    'custom_apply_to_products' => null,
    'custom_design_from' => null,
    'custom_design_to' => null,
    'custom_layout_update' => null,
    'default_sort_by' => 'position',
    'description' => $cat_name,
    'display_mode' => null,
    'is_anchor' => 0,
    'landing_page' => null,
    'meta_description' => $cat_name,
    'meta_keywords' => $cat_name,
    'meta_title' => $cat_name,
    'page_layout' => 'two_columns_left',
    'url_key' => $cat_url,
    'include_in_menu' => 1,
));

// Print Result = New Category ID
// var_dump ($result);

return $result;
```

It was working perfectly fine until last Wednesday when the Schema server went down for couple of hours. Any idea how to by pass the error, or fix it?

**UPDATED - Problem "Resolved"**

I changed from v2 SOAP, to just plain SOAP. Had to modify the API call a bit. It appears there is a problem with v2 SOAP...

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.create', array(2, array(
    'name' => $cat_name,
    'is_active' => 1,
    'available_sort_by' => 'position',
    'custom_design' => null,
    'custom_apply_to_products' => null,
    'custom_design_from' => null,
    'custom_design_to' => null,
    'custom_layout_update' => null,
    'default_sort_by' => 'position',
    'description' => $cat_name,
    'display_mode' => null,
    'is_anchor' => 1,
    'landing_page' => null,
    'meta_description' => $cat_name,
    'meta_keywords' => $cat_name,
    'meta_title' => $cat_name,
    'page_layout' => 'two_columns_left',
    'url_key' => $cat_url,
    'include_in_menu' => 0,
)));
```

Comment: Well I sort of fixed the problem... I changed the API from v2 SOAP to just plain SOAP. I had to modify my API requests for the change as they're not the same. See notes above...

Comment: Add your answer and accept it, its okay to do such.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the value for the default_sort_by field is invalid, because you use a empty value. Depending on the field that you want to use for sorting you need to enter it here, for example you could use position:

for example:

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.update', array(181, array(
                'is_anchor' => 1,
                'include_in_menu' => 0,
                'available_sort_by' => "position",
                'default_sort_by' => "position",
            )));
```

The code above should work, other options that are there by default are 'name' and 'price'. If you want another attribute to use as sortable field, you can set the option 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' to 'Yes' for the attribute thru that admin option Catalog => Attributes => Manage Attributes

**or other solution is:**

I changed the settings in all store views, but it didn't changed in all sotre views. When I tried to change the setting Use Default Value in my "languagesviews". I get the error "Default Product Listing Sort by not exists on Available Product Listing Sort By".

So I "just" need to change all categorysettings of each language.

EDIT:

After editing some categories and checking/unchecking "use default values" the error is gone and I set all "use default values" to yes.

so you need to check the checkbox default use in display settings.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I specified I am using the default POSITION for the sort by, but it is still producing this error which makes no sense to me...

In addition, your code is invalid... available_sort_by expects an ARRAY and not a value.

Comment: Please choose default settings from admin dispay settings I hope this can be a trick for your question to solve errors.

Comment: That did not help either, it's like it cannot find POSITION which is a default sort by attribute. Which is extremely weird. The above code was working perfectly for weeks straight, until Schema went down for a few hours... since then I've been getting this error...

Comment: Have you any previous back up? For db also?

Comment: Also try to print_r($result). Because this error raise when default parameters pass with null value.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes I do, but it does not have the 1400 categories and 160,000 products imported. The script was running for almost 4 weeks straight importing categories and products from the supplier.

Comment: It will not show the result since its throwing the error. It stops the script before it can return the result.

Comment: I will also add if I change POSITION for PRICE or NAME it does the exact same thing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33526/discussion-between-jcastell-and-denish-vachhani).

Comment: This is late night 11.30 pm so its can be possible tomorrow. But after company hours. I hope you can understand.